# How to apply IIFE in ReactJS + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iife

I would like to use IIFE in ReactJS + Typescript environment. So i rewrite this code with ReactJS + Typescript

**IIFE**

```
(function() { 
        //Constructor
        this.Radio = function(){ 

            var defaults = { 
                locale: "en-US", 
            }

        } 

        // Public Methods   
        Radio.prototype.load = function() { 

        } 
      }());
```

**ReactJS + Typescript**

```
    export default class Radio{
    options: any = { 
        locale: "en-US", 

    };
    constructor(props: any) {
        var defaults = { 
            locale: "en-US", 
        }

    }       

    // Public Methods   
    load = () => { 
    }
}
```

What i try to achieve is when the bundle.js load from html page i'm able to instantiate by passing some value in like below

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<body> 


    <div id="app"></div>

</body> 

<script>
    $(function() {
        var test = new Radio({   <----error on this line         
            locale: "en-US",            
        });
        test.load();
    });
</script>
```

But when i run above code i got this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: Radio is not defined**

Is that possible to implement IIFE like above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when i run above code i got this error Uncaught ReferenceError: Radio is not defined

If you want this old code to still work you need to put `Radio` on this just like old times. E.g.

```
 export default class Radio{
    options: any = { 
        locale: "en-US", 

    };
    constructor(props: any) {
        var defaults = { 
            locale: "en-US", 
        }

    }       

    // Public Methods   
    load = () => { 
    }
} 

// ADD
(window as any).Radio = Radio;
```

Comment: what is the line mean? after added i still have the same error

Comment: Try again `window as any` 

Comment: Means "export to global" so it can be used in *all* script tags 

Comment: hmm... The first line is not considered export?

Comment: The first line is an "export as a module".

Comment: The last line is "export as global"